# Быстрый заказ WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В сети есть множество плагинов с заказом в один клик, но они все работают по принципу формы обратной связи. Весь учет заказов в какой-то отдельной таблице.

Подскажите, как примерно будет выглядеть запрос на добавления товара в корзину с переходом на страницу оформления заказа?

Comment: Или возможно построить запрос создания заказа прямо с фронта с основными переменными id продукта и email по которому будет присвоен клиент

Comment: Не в той Сети ищете. https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-checkout/